# Correlation coefficient of multiple 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, 2d, correlation

I'd like to find the correlation coefficient between two 2D arrays. One array contains variables and the other contains observations. The arrays both have shapes of `(145,192)` containing global rainfall data.

I was trying to find a way to use `np.corrcoef`, but based on the documentation I've seen, if it's a 2D array it assumes it contains both variables and observations. Is there a way to use this function to compare the arrays? Will I have to alter the arrays at all?

Sorry if this isn't explained very well. If more details are needed let me know.

Comment: Is it like a row-wise correlation that you are looking for between the two arrays?

Comment: I believe so. Essentially, what I ultimately want is to be able to do is make a map of the correlation, so I want a value for each data point and have a final array with shape `(145, 192)` as well. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: Can you please add the code that you have so far and examples to produce an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?